# Receive notification when RegistryKey Value was changed

Tags: c#, registry, wmi, notifications, wbem

I want a notification when a specific RegistryKey in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is changed.
So far I tried this via `WMI` with no success:

```
var query = new WqlEventQuery(string.Format(
"SELECT * FROM RegistryKeyChangeEvent WHERE Hive='{0}' AND KeyPath='{1}' AND ValueName='{2}'",
                hive, keyPath.Replace("\\","\\\\"), valueName));
_watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
_watcher.Scope.Path.NamespacePath = @"root\default";
_watcher.EventArrived += (sender, args) => KeyValueChanged();
_watcher.Start();
```

(Error was "Not found")

My second approach was using the `WBEM Scripting COM component` with the intent to port the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393042(VS.85).aspx to c# but I didn't find any usage samples for the WBEM COM in c#

I found this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/registrymonitor.aspx class, but it didn't fit my needs as this class only monitors the whole key and I only want a notification when a specific value (specified via the `ValueName` in the samples above) gets changed.

EDIT:
If you change the Hive to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` in the msdn vbscript example, it stops working. I couldn't find anything about this behaviour but [a link from 2003](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/monitor-registry-entry-level-events-help-25036722.html?page=1#25057792)

EDIT2:
Changes to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hives are not supported by `RegistryEvent` or classes derived from it, such as `RegistryValueChangeEvent`. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393042%28v=VS.85%29.aspx))

Comment: I believe you can modify the code-project code to use multiple wait handles/monitors to all least tell which key has been changed. I am not sure what the implications of n monitors are though -- doesn't seem so bad: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally solved the problem and got the WMI query version to work:

```
var currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
var query = new WqlEventQuery(string.Format(
"SELECT * FROM RegistryValueChangeEvent WHERE Hive='HKEY_USERS' AND KeyPath='{0}\\\\{1}' AND ValueName='{2}'",
currentUser.User.Value, keyPath.Replace("\\","\\\\"), valueName));
_watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
_watcher.EventArrived += (sender, args) => KeyValueChanged();
_watcher.Start();
```

I found this "hack" at http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2844468/Monitoring-HKEY_CURRENT_USER.aspx

Comment: Did you run into an issue where this event would only fire once?

Comment: Thanks!  In my case, it was with RootPath:
                var currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                String registryCallbackQuery = String.Format(
                    "SELECT * FROM RegistryTreeChangeEvent "
                    + " WHERE Hive='HKEY_USERS' "
                    + " AND RootPath='{0}\\\\{1}'",
                    currentUser.User.Value,
                    keyPath.Replace("\\", "\\\\")
                );

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded to pastbin a nice class that does it. Hope it fits your needs.

http://www.csharp.pastebin.com/0reFh6v2

Comment: This looks like the RegistryMonitor class from codeproject which as I mentioned in my question does not fit my needs because it notifies if any value in the key changes and not only if a specific one changes...

Comment: @RoXX can't you just iterate through the values that changed and see if the one you wanted did?

Comment: I could but there are a lot of other values which change and it would be nice if I could filter them out at a lower level like with the wmi query, I'm looking for a nicer solution.

Comment: I've reviewed the codeproject class again and it doesn't provide any information on which ValueName has changed in its event and so I would have to manually check if my key has changed and this would have a huge performance impact which makes this aproach useless for me