# Get Visio theme color

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-interop, add-in, visio

In Visio you can set the theme of your Visio `File > Options > General > Office Theme`. I would like to retrieve this value in my addin in visual studio so that I can adjust my own custom windows. However I can not find this setting. Can somebody tell me where I can find it or how I can access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the value of the DWORD registry key `UI Theme` which can be found under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\1x.0\Common
```

Replace the `1x.0` with your Office version number which is currently `15.0` for Office 2013 or `16.0` for Office 2016.

The possible values for Office 2013 are:

- `0` White
- `1` Light Grey
- `2` Dark Grey

The possible values for Office 2016 are:

- `0` Colorful
- `3` Dark Grey
- `4` Black (not available in all versions)
- `5` White

It's also possible to listen for theme changes using `ManagementEventWatcher.EventArrived` like shown here: [Receive notification when RegistryKey Value was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233746/receive-notification-when-registrykey-value-was-changed)